# SELECTing data from multiples schemas with a JPQL query

Tags: java, mysql, spring-data-jpa, mariadb, jpql

I have a MariaDB database with 2 schemas : Store1 and Store2. These schemas contain several tables. "Products" is one of these.

In my repository, I need to add the following request :

```
@Query("SELECT Store1.Products.Id, Store1.Products.Label FROM Store1.Products UNION SELECT Store2.Products.Id, Store2.Products.Label FROM Store2.Products")
public Page<Products> getAllProducts(Pageable pageable);
```

Of course, the query doesn't work, it's just for an example about what I want to do.
I've briefly read about multi-tenancy, but I don't know if it fits my use case, and seems complex for such a simple case.

Is there a simpler way to get this query ?

Comment: `@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT * FROM Store1.Products UNION SELECT * FROM Store2.Products")` should work.

Comment: @manish thank you for your answer, but it doesn't work. The error message tells me that I have to configure a datasource, what I've done in my application.yml file :

jdbc:mariadb://db.mycompany.intra:3306

Comment: Can you do a simpler query?  That is, is the problem with the _configuration_ or with the _query_?